# DigitalOcean Dokku droplet

Tags: digital-ocean, dokku

So i did set up successfully a droplet on Digitalocean via Dokku for a Rails app.

Does anyone know what the default url address to the app is, without an Domain? I don't have domain for the app yet, and i know there was a way (just forget how) to access the app even without adding a domain. I tried to use the ip4 address with a / and the app name, but it won't work.

Once i pushed the git with dokku to the droplet, i got the standard log back that everything worked fine and that the app is deployed at:

```
Application deployed:
       http://myproject:2297
```

When i try to visit this link, i got a 'this site can't be reached error'.

App is running successfully, confirmed via dokku logs.

Any ideas how i can visit my app?

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to fix it.

Just in case anyone else is running into this problem as well.

Make sure to be logged in to your droplet via Terminal and run:

```
dokku domains:report
```

this will show you all domains that are set. In my case, the domain was set to false.

I simply ran:

```
dokku domains:add add_your_dokku_app_name_here whatever
```

in this case, the domain will be set to "whatever"

The app can now be visited by simply using your ip4 address inside the browser.

Greetings!